# NPM install downloads modules which are not related to project dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm-install

the dependencies section of package.json of this particular project looks like.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^2.2.4",
    "request": "^2.72.0",
    "request-json": "^0.5.6"
  }
```

when I type NPM Install the node_modules folder looks like:

```
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          .
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          ..
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          .bin
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          ansi-regex
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          ansi-styles
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          asn1
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          assert-plus
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          async
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          aws-sign2
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          aws4
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          bl
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          boom
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          caseless
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          chalk
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          combined-stream
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          commander
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          core-util-is
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          cryptiles
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          dashdash
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          delayed-stream
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          depd
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          ecc-jsbn
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          escape-string-regexp
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          extend
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          extsprintf
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          forever-agent
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          form-data
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          generate-function
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          generate-object-property
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          getpass
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          graceful-readlink
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          har-validator
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          has-ansi
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          hawk
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          hoek
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          http-signature
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          inherits
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          is-my-json-valid
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          is-property
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          is-typedarray
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          isarray
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          isstream
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          jodid25519
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          jquery
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          jsbn
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          json-schema
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          json-stringify-safe
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          jsonpointer
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          jsprim
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          mime-db
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          mime-types
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          node-uuid
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          oauth-sign
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          pinkie
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          pinkie-promise
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          process-nextick-args
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          qs
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          readable-stream
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          request
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          request-json
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          sntp
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          sshpk
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          stringstream
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          string_decoder
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          strip-ansi
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          supports-color
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          tough-cookie
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          tunnel-agent
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          tweetnacl
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          util-deprecate
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          verror
06/12/2016  12:12 AM    <DIR>          xtend
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
              72 Dir(s)  417,568,436,224 bytes free
```

**It is my understanding that the local node_modules folder for this project should only include the packages listed in dependencies?**

Why are all these other packages being installed which are not related to my project?

I have this same problem with every node project on my PC. I assume this is a windows issue.

When I use `NPM Prune` nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

They are the dependencies that are listed in the modules that you list or the modules that your dependent modules dependencies have or any iteration of this logic.

Answer (score 0):

These are dependencies of the modules your project depends on (those in your package.json file)

If you use `npm ls` you will get a pretty-printed list of modules in your project, and the modules they depend on.

Answer (score 0):

Since NPM 3+, all dependencies are flattened, to better "re-use" shared dependencies between different modules if the version matches.

If you don't want that behavior, downgrading to npm 2 seems to be the only way.